# Named Entity Recognition IOB annotation transformation

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

How can an IOB (Intermediate, Other, Begin) annotation format like "John/B-PERSON Doe/I_PERSON..." be transformed into some other formats that can be digested in Java?

Could not figure it out from the documentation of Stanford NLP related classes: IOBUtils and  CoNLLDocumentReaderAndWriter

Comment: If you downloaded the source, try looking into the `main` methods in both these classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method I wrote to show usage of CoNLLDocumentReaderAndWriter:

```
public static Iterator<List<CoreLabel>> loadCoNLLDocuments(String filePath) throws IOException{
    SeqClassifierFlags inputFlags = new SeqClassifierFlags();
    inputFlags.entitySubclassification = "noprefix";
    inputFlags.retainEntitySubclassification = true;
    CoNLLDocumentReaderAndWriter rw = new CoNLLDocumentReaderAndWriter();
    rw.init(inputFlags);
    Iterator<List<CoreLabel>> documents = rw.getIterator(IOUtils.readerFromString(filePath));
    return documents;       
}
```

The key line is where entitySubclassification is set.  In this example I converted the tags to no prefix style (e.g. ORG, PER, MISC)

So for instance if your input is in IOB, and you set entitySubclassification to "noprefix" , the CoreLabels will have the prefixes stripped off.

All of the options are listed in IOBUtils in the method entitySubclassify:

iob1, iob2, bio, ioe1, ioe2, io, sbieo, iobes, noprefix, bilou

To test this out, you should use an input file with one type, and then try translating it to another.  You can then see what the tags are for the tokens:

```
// The documents are List<CoreLabel>, token is a CoreLabel

String tokenTag = token.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class) ;
```

When I print out using my code above I am seeing the correct conversion!

Note that the input file is of the form "token\tner_tag" per line, for instance "John\tI-PERSON" , though the reader can also handle a variety of CoNLL style input formats, including the original "token\tpos\tchunk\tner_tag" per line format.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String sent = "When/O the/O last/O time/O you/O ran/O into/O Rick/B-person Ross/I-person and/O Drake/B-person twice/O in/O the/O same/O day/O at/O 2/O diff/O video/O shoot/O locations/O ./O Today/O I/O did/O !/O";

    String[] result = sent.split("/| ");
    for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++) {
        if ( result[x].length() != 0 ) {
            System.out.print(result[x]);
            x++;
            System.out.println("\t" + result[x]);
        }
    }
```